# Select multiple columns by labels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking around for ways to select columns through the python documentation and the forums but every example on indexing columns are too simplistic.

Suppose I have a 10 x 10 dataframe

```
df = DataFrame(randn(10, 10), index=range(0,10), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J'])
```

So far, all the documentations gives is just a simple example of indexing like

```
subset = df.loc[:,'A':'C']
```

or

```
subset = df.loc[:,'C':]
```

But I get an error when I try index multiple, non-sequential columns, like this

```
subset = df.loc[:,('A':'C', 'E')]
```

How would I index in Pandas if I wanted to select column A to C, E, and G to I? It appears that this logic will not work

```
subset = df.loc[:,('A':'C', 'E', 'G':'I')]
```

I feel that the solution is pretty simple, but I can't get around this error. Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to build a list of all the columns of interest and pass this like so `df[col_list]`, the problem here is that parsing this would become problematic because `('A':'C')` is not a valid tuple anyway

Comment: This is not possible with normal indexing: you can either give a slice (like `'A':'C'`), or either a list of labels (like `['A', 'B', 'C']`), but not a combination of both.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

#### Name- or Label-Based (using regular expression syntax)

```
df.filter(regex='[A-CEG-I]')   # does NOT depend on the column order
```

Note that any regular expression is allowed here, so this approach can be very general.  E.g. if you wanted all columns starting with a capital or lowercase "A" you could use:  `df.filter(regex='^[Aa]')`

#### Location-Based (depends on column order)

```
df[ list(df.loc[:,'A':'C']) + ['E'] + list(df.loc[:,'G':'I']) ]
```

Note that unlike the label-based method, this only works if your columns are alphabetically sorted.  This is not necessarily a problem, however.  For example, if your columns go `['A','C','B']`, then you could replace `'A':'C'` above with `'A':'B'`.

#### The Long Way

And for completeness, you always have the option shown by @Magdalena of simply listing each column individually, although it could be much more verbose as the number of columns increases:

```
df[['A','B','C','E','G','H','I']]   # does NOT depend on the column order
```

#### Results for any of the above methods

```
          A         B         C         E         G         H         I
0 -0.814688 -1.060864 -0.008088  2.697203 -0.763874  1.793213 -0.019520
1  0.549824  0.269340  0.405570 -0.406695 -0.536304 -1.231051  0.058018
2  0.879230 -0.666814  1.305835  0.167621 -1.100355  0.391133  0.317467
```

Comment: Note that in the first solution, you can further select certain rows, using df[["0, 1"],cols]. Also note that the "list" hack used in the cols variable doesn't work for making a similar selection for rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 40):

Just pick the columns you want directly....

```
df[['A','E','I','C']]
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more for the OP?

Comment: Dont understand why this is not marked as the accepted answer. Every other answer seems complicated

Comment: Because of: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: It would be helpful to qualify that this simple solution works only if your desire is to read, not write, the resultant subset of the dataframe. OP did not clarify read vs. write intent.

Comment: @code-assassin This answer is mostly orrect but OP is quite specifically asking for short-cut methods to specify **multiple** column **ranges**. This answer will be more verbose in many cases. Also note that in this case the fully written out answer is not exactly as shown above but `df[['A','B','C','E','G','H','I']]`.

Comment: Btw, I have added @magdalena's approach to my answer (while giving credit) as I couldn't decide if it was better to edit someone else's answer or just use it to improve my answer.  magdalena -- if you are still around, I would suggest editing as in my previous comment here (if you agree with it, of course)

Answer (score 4):

> #### How do I select multiple columns by labels in pandas?

Multiple label-based range slicing is not easily supported with pandas, but position-based slicing is, so let's try that instead:

```
loc = df.columns.get_loc
df.iloc[:, np.r_[loc('A'):loc('C')+1, loc('E'), loc('G'):loc('I')+1]]

          A         B         C         E         G         H         I
0 -1.666330  0.321260 -1.768185 -0.034774  0.023294  0.533451 -0.241990
1  0.911498  3.408758  0.419618 -0.462590  0.739092  1.103940  0.116119
2  1.243001 -0.867370  1.058194  0.314196  0.887469  0.471137 -1.361059
3 -0.525165  0.676371  0.325831 -1.152202  0.606079  1.002880  2.032663
4  0.706609 -0.424726  0.308808  1.994626  0.626522 -0.033057  1.725315
5  0.879802 -1.961398  0.131694 -0.931951 -0.242822 -1.056038  0.550346
6  0.199072  0.969283  0.347008 -2.611489  0.282920 -0.334618  0.243583
7  1.234059  1.000687  0.863572  0.412544  0.569687 -0.684413 -0.357968
8 -0.299185  0.566009 -0.859453 -0.564557 -0.562524  0.233489 -0.039145
9  0.937637 -2.171174 -1.940916 -1.553634  0.619965 -0.664284 -0.151388
```

Note that the `+1` is added because when using `iloc` the rightmost index is exclusive.

---

#### Comments on Other Solutions

- `filter` is a nice and simple method for OP's headers, but this might not generalise well to arbitrary column names.
- The "location-based" solution with `loc` is a little closer to the ideal, but you cannot avoid creating intermediate DataFrames (that are eventually thrown out and garbage collected) to compute the final result range -- something that we would ideally like to avoid.
- Lastly, "pick your columns directly" is good advice as long as you have a manageably small number of columns to pick. It will, however not be applicable in some cases where ranges span dozens (or possibly hundreds) of columns.

Comment: I think filter generalize extremely well because it accepts regular expressions but maybe that wasn't clear so I just edited my answer to make this more obvious.

Comment: It's a good point about intermediate data sets, however, I'm not sure your `r_` way is significantly better.  I just did a quick timing of the OP data expanded to 1,000,000 rows and both of our ways are much slower than on the OP data with 10 rows.  Admittedly your way is about 7% faster, but it's not clear it doesn't suffer from the same basic problem of taking longer for a larger dataframe.  It does occur to me that either of our ways could probably be easily patched by just working on the first row of the dataframe.

Comment: @JohnE Thanks for the comments. This is a different way of looking at a problem, not necessarily the best way, but might bring some gains depending on OP's data.

Answer (score 0):

One option for selecting multiple slices is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select_columns.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
from numpy import random
random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame(
            random.randn(10, 10), 
            index=range(0,10), 
            columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
            )

df.select_columns(slice('A', 'C'), 'E', slice('G', 'I'))

          A         B         C         E         G         H         I
0  1.788628  0.436510  0.096497 -0.277388 -0.082741 -0.627001 -0.043818
1 -1.313865  0.884622  0.881318  0.050034 -0.545360 -1.546477  0.982367
2 -1.185047 -0.205650  1.486148 -1.023785  0.625245 -0.160513 -0.768836
3  0.745056  1.976111 -1.244123 -0.803766 -0.923792 -1.023876  1.123978
4 -1.623285  0.646675 -0.356271 -0.596650 -0.873882  0.029714 -2.248258
5  1.013183  0.852798  1.108187  1.487543  0.845833 -1.860890 -0.602885
6  1.048148  1.333738 -0.197415 -0.674728  0.152946 -1.064195  0.437947
7 -1.024931  0.899338 -0.154507  0.483788  0.643163  0.249087 -1.395764
8 -1.370669  0.238563  0.614077  0.145063 -0.024104 -0.888657 -2.915738
9 -0.591079 -0.516417 -0.959996 -0.574708  0.679072 -0.855437 -0.300206
```

The caveat here is that you have to explicitly use python's builtin `slice`.

Just like the excellent chosen answer, you can use regular expressions, again, it is explicit use (python's `re`):

```py
import re

 df.select_columns(re.compile('[A-CEG-I]'))

          A         B         C         E         G         H         I
0  1.788628  0.436510  0.096497 -0.277388 -0.082741 -0.627001 -0.043818
1 -1.313865  0.884622  0.881318  0.050034 -0.545360 -1.546477  0.982367
2 -1.185047 -0.205650  1.486148 -1.023785  0.625245 -0.160513 -0.768836
3  0.745056  1.976111 -1.244123 -0.803766 -0.923792 -1.023876  1.123978
4 -1.623285  0.646675 -0.356271 -0.596650 -0.873882  0.029714 -2.248258
5  1.013183  0.852798  1.108187  1.487543  0.845833 -1.860890 -0.602885
6  1.048148  1.333738 -0.197415 -0.674728  0.152946 -1.064195  0.437947
7 -1.024931  0.899338 -0.154507  0.483788  0.643163  0.249087 -1.395764
8 -1.370669  0.238563  0.614077  0.145063 -0.024104 -0.888657 -2.915738
9 -0.591079 -0.516417 -0.959996 -0.574708  0.679072 -0.855437 -0.300206
```

You can go crazy and combine different selection options within the `select_columns` method.