# pandas time series multiple slice

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, time-series, slice

I can see from the pandas documentation that you can go:

```
df.loc[['a','b','c'],:]
```

For time series, why can you not go:

```
x = df.loc[['2005-10-27 14:30':'2005-10-27 15:15', '2006-04-14 14:40':'2006-04-14 15:20', '2008-01-25 14:30':'2008-01-25 15:30'],:]
```

I get a syntax error. Can you not do multiple sliced ranges on a time series? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You are attempting to index with strings not Timestamps. And you are trying to use a list of slice objects.

Comment: It's not really related to time series.  You can't combine slices and lists like that in general.  Main option is to manually construct a list as Mark does below.  See here also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241836/select-multiple-columns-by-labels-pandas/29242900#29242900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a DataFrame index will accept a list of column indexes, it will not accept a list of row slice objects.

This should do what you want, it loops through your desired ranges compiling a new DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# let's create some fake data
date_range = pd.date_range('2005-01-01', '2008-12-31', freq='9min')
l = len(date_range)
df = pd.DataFrame({'normal': np.random.randn(l), 'uniform':np.random.rand(l), 
    'datetime':date_range, 'integer':range(l)}, index=date_range)

# let's identify the periods we want
desired = [('2005-10-27 14:30','2005-10-27 15:15'), 
           ('2006-04-14 14:40','2006-04-14 15:20'), 
           ('2008-01-25 14:30','2008-01-25 15:30')]

# let's loop through the desired ranges and compile our selection           
x = pd.DataFrame()
for (start, stop) in desired:
    selection = df[(df.index >= pd.Timestamp(start)) & 
        (df.index <= pd.Timestamp(stop))]
    x = x.append(selection)

# and let's have a look at what we found ...
print(x)
```

Comment: Good answer, although for efficiency (in cases where it matters) you might prefer to do this only on the index instead of on the whole dataframe.

Comment: Is there no more efficient way of doing this, i.e., avoiding the loop? If the desired intervals don't overlap one can avoid the loop by using np.searchsorted, but that breaks if intervals overlap...

Comment: @feilchenfeldt [this](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html) article, especially on `IndexSlice`s may fit your use case.

Comment: Why the comparisons? Pandas supports slicing with date strings. `selection = df[slice(start, stop)]` should work. Or `x = pd.concat([df[slice(*date_range)] for date_range in desired])`

Answer (score 5):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393856/python-pandas-slice-dataframe-by-multiple-index-ranges) mentions numpy.r_ but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work with a list of slices so I used hstack and arange

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def loop_version(df, desired):
    # let's loop through the desired ranges and compile our selection           
    x = pd.DataFrame()
    for (start, stop) in desired:
        selection = df[(df.index >= pd.Timestamp(start)) & 
            (df.index <= pd.Timestamp(stop))]
        x = x.append(selection)

    # and let's have a look at what we found ...
    return x

def vectorized_version(df, desired):
    # first flatten the list
    times = np.array(desired).flatten()
    # use searchsorted to find the indices of the 
    # desired times in df's index
    ndxlist = df.index.searchsorted(np.array(times))
    # use np.arange to convert pairs of values in ndxlist to a 
    # range of indices, similar to np.r_
    ndxlist = np.hstack([np.arange(i1, i2) for i1, i2 in 
                        zip(ndxlist[::2], ndxlist[1::2])])
    return df.iloc[ndxlist]

In [2]: # let's create some fake data
In [3]: date_range = pd.date_range('2005-01-01', '2008-12-31', freq='9min')
In [4]: l = len(date_range)
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'normal': np.random.randn(l), 'uniform':np.random.rand(l), 
   ...:     'datetime':date_range, 'integer':range(l)}, index=date_range)
In [6]: # let's identify the periods we want
   ...: desired = [('2005-10-27 14:30','2005-10-27 15:15'), 
   ...:            ('2006-04-14 14:40','2006-04-14 15:20'), 
   ...:            ('2008-01-25 14:30','2008-01-25 15:30')]

In [7]: loop_version(df, desired).equals(vectorized_version(df, desired))
Out[7]: True

In [8]: % timeit loop_version(df, desired)
5.53 ms ± 225 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [9]: % timeit vectorized_version(df, desired)
308 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Agreed, for large dataframes this is hugely more efficient, provided there is no overlap in times.