# Python pandas slice dataframe by multiple index ranges

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

What is the pythonic way to slice a dataframe by more index ranges (eg. by `10:12` and `25:28`)?

I want this in a more elegant way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10,100)})
df.iloc[[i for i in range(10,12)] + [i for i in range(25,28)]]
```

Result:

```
     a
10  20
11  21
25  35
26  36
27  37
```

Something like this would be more elegant:

```
df.iloc[(10:12, 25:28)]
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use numpy's [`r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) "slicing trick":

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10,100)})
df.iloc[pd.np.r_[10:12, 25:28]]
```

NOTE: this now gives a warning `The pandas.np module is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import numpy directly instead`. To do that, you can `import numpy as np` and then slice the following way:

```
df.iloc[np.r_[10:12, 25:28]]
```

This gives:

```
     a
10  20
11  21
25  35
26  36
27  37
```

Comment: It doesn't get much more concise than this.  `np.r_` was built for exactly this purpose.  And, I learned something.  Wish I could +2.

Comment: one thing to note: to get negative indexing (i.e. the equivalent of `df.iloc[-2:]`), you must include a zero: `df.iloc[pd.np.r_[:2, -2:0]]`

Comment: `pd.np.r_` is deprecated so I have updated the answer to use numpy directly

Comment: love this. works much faster than selecting individual ranges and concat them ...

Comment: Is there no native or pandas solution available, rather than using Numpy?

Answer (score 8):

You can take advantage of pandas isin function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10,100)})
ls = [i for i in range(10,12)] + [i for i in range(25,28)]
df[df.index.isin(ls)]


    a
10  20
11  21
25  35
26  36
27  37
```

Comment: Came here for this... thanks! Provided an answer that incorporates yours.

Comment: you can also use ls = `list(range(10,12)) + list(range(25,28))`

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @KevinOelen's use of Panda's isin function, here is a pythonic way (Python 3.8) to glance at a Pandas DataFrame or GeoPandas GeoDataFrame revealing just a few rows of the head and tail. This method does not require importing numpy.

To use just call glance(your_df). Additional explanation in docstring.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd  # if not needed, remove gpd.GeoDataFrame from the type hinting and no need to import Union
from typing import Union


def glance(df: Union[pd.DataFrame, gpd.GeoDataFrame], size: int = 2) -> None:
    """ Provides a shortened head and tail summary of a Dataframe or GeoDataFrame in Jupyter Notebook or Lab.

    Usage
    ----------
    # default glance (2 head rows, 2 tail rows)
    glance( df )
    
    # glance defined number of rows in head and tail (3 head rows, 3 tails rows)
    glance( df, size=3 )

    Parameters
    ----------
    :param df: Union[pd.DataFrame, gpd.GeoDataFrame]: A (Geo)Pandas data frame to glance at.
    :param size: int: The number of rows in the head and tail to display, total rows will be double provided size.
    :return: None: Displays result in Notebook or Lab.
    """
    
    # min and max of the provided dataframe index
    min_ = df.index.min()
    max_ = df.index.max()

    # define slice
    sample = [i for i in range(min_, size)] + [i for i in range(max_ - size, max_)]

    # slice
    df = df[df.index.isin(sample)]
    
    # display
    display( df )
```