# Pandas first 5 and last 5 rows in single iloc operation

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check `df.head()` and `df.tail()` many times. 
When using `df.head(), df.tail()` jupyter notebook dispalys the ugly output.

Is there any single line command so that we can select only first 5 and last 5 rows:

something like:
`df.iloc[:5 | -5:] ?`

Test example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,2))
df.iloc[:5]
```

**Update**
Ugly but working ways:

```
df.iloc[(np.where( (df.index < 5) | (df.index > len(df)-5)))[0]]

or,
df.iloc[np.r_[np.arange(5), np.arange(df.shape[0]-5, df.shape[0])]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try look at `numpy.r_`

```
df.iloc[np.r_[0:5, -5:0]]
Out[358]: 
           0         1
0   0.899673  0.584707
1   0.443328  0.126370
2   0.203212  0.206542
3   0.562156  0.401226
4   0.085070  0.206960
15  0.082846  0.548997
16  0.435308  0.669673
17  0.426955  0.030303
18  0.327725  0.340572
19  0.250246  0.162993
```

Also `head` + `tail` is not a bad solution

```
df.head(5).append(df.tail(5))
Out[362]: 
           0         1
0   0.899673  0.584707
1   0.443328  0.126370
2   0.203212  0.206542
3   0.562156  0.401226
4   0.085070  0.206960
15  0.082846  0.548997
16  0.435308  0.669673
17  0.426955  0.030303
18  0.327725  0.340572
19  0.250246  0.162993
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had tried `df.iloc[np.r_[np.arange(5), np.arange(df.shape[0]-5, df.shape[0])]]` but it was ugly.

Comment: @astro123 check the update , I further cut the , to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

`df.query("index<5 | index>"+str(len(df)-5))`

Here's a way to query the index. You can change the values to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, Query is super easy to use but it is recommended not to use for small dataset of order `<15k` rows, anyways, upvoted for nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727239/4057186) SO post)

- uses only Pandas [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin)

Generate some dummy/demo data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10,100)})

print(df.head())
    a
0  10
1  11
2  12
3  13
4  14

print(df.tail())
     a
85  95
86  96
87  97
88  98
89  99

print(df.shape)
(90, 1)
```

Generate list of required indexes

```
ls = list(range(5)) + list(range(len(df)-5, len(df)))

print(ls)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
```

Slice `DataFrame` using list of indexes

```
df_first_last_5 = df[df.index.isin(ls)]

print(df_first_last_5)
     a
0   10
1   11
2   12
3   13
4   14
85  95
86  96
87  97
88  98
89  99
```

Comment: This is the most general way, and I was simply trying to aviod it. `df.iloc[list(range(5)) + list(range(len(df)-5, len(df)))]` simply works, `.isin` is overkill.