# Subsetting columns that are two groups of consecutive number

Tags: python

Hi I know in R if I have a data frame, df, if I want to just cal the first ten columns and the 12th-17th columns, I can do this: df[,c(1:10,12:17)]. Is there a way to do this in python with the pandas library? What about for just any general ndarray? I am new to python so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pandas slice dataframe by multiple index ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393856/python-pandas-slice-dataframe-by-multiple-index-ranges)

Answer (score 0):

U might want to check this thread ([multiple slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393856/python-pandas-slice-dataframe-by-multiple-index-ranges)).
U can use the r_ of numpy

```
df.iloc[pd.np.r_[1:10, 12:17]]
```