# Get all items from df's column that are within a range, using ranges iterable

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, range

I want to create a function that I can apply on a df's column which will identify all entries in that column ('C2017Value') that are within any of the ranges in a list of ranges (ranges)...and output the corresponding entries within ranges and their c value to a results dictionary, {'c' : C2017Value},  like so:

```
results = {'c3': 268} #268 is within one of the ranges
```

I'm stuck on the code and will appreciate any insights and feedback.

```
df #dataframe with two columns, 'c' and C2017Value
 'c1', 137674167
 'c2',  2166178
 'c3',  268

ranges = [
 (261, 4760),
 (12273391, 11104571063),
 (45695385, 4134339925),
 (15266178, 1376748162),
 (10106104, 97810284),
 (6492248, 588025190)
 ]
```

Here are my attempts at this function:

```
between_range = [c2017 for c2017
               in sorted(ranges)
               if ranges[0] <= value <= ranges[1]
               ][0]

def get_output_list(c2017value):
  output_list = []
  index = 0
  for c in df:
    if ranges[0][0] <= c2017value <= ranges[0][1]:
      output_list.append(c)
    else:
      index += 1
  return output_list

def get_output_list0(df, ranges):
  output_list = []
  index = 0
  for c in df:
    if c.column_value('C2017Value') == xrange() ranges[index]:
      output_list.append(c)
    else:
      index += 1
  return output_list

def get_output_list1(C2017Value):
    for x, y in sorted(ranges):
        if any(x <= C2017Value < y):
            for c in ms_df:
                output.append(c)

def get_output_list2(CValue):
    output = []
    ranges = get_ranges()
    for c in ms_df:
        ##if MINvalue<= CValue <=MAXvalue:
        if C2017Value in ranges(MINvalue, MAXvalue):
            return c
            output.append(c)
            break

def get_output_list3(C2017Value):
    ##ranges = get_ranges()
    for c in df:
        ##if MINvalue<= CValue <=MAXvalue:
        if CValue in ranges:
            return c

def get_output_list4(df, C2017Value, ranges[0:1]):
    ##ranges = get_ranges()
    for c in df_countries:
    ##if MINvalue<= CValue <=MAXvalue:
        if C2017Value in ranges:
        #if C2017Value in range(ranges):    
        #return c
            output.append(c)
            return output

def get_output_list5(C2017Value:
    for c in df_countries:
        for x in sorted(ranges):
            range_list = ranges[range_name]
            if any(start <= number < end for start,end):
                results.setdefault(range_name, 0) += 1

def get_output_list6(C2017Value):
    for c in ms_df:
        for x, y in sorted(ranges):
            if any(x <= C2017Value < y):
                output.append(c)
```

These two are probably the most promising attempts:

```
between_range = [c2017 for c2017
               in sorted(ranges)
               if ranges[0] <= value <= ranges[1]
               ][0]


def get_output_list(c2017value):
  output_list = []
  index = 0
  for c in df:
    if ranges[0][0] <= c2017value <= ranges[0][1]:
      output_list.append(c)
    else:
      index += 1
  return output_list
```

between_range gets the following error message:
"<= not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: if you get `<= not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"` then you should check what you compare - maybe you compare `261 <=  'c3'` instead of `261 <= 268`

Comment: how about `df[ df['C2017Value'].between(261, 4760) ]` ? it gives all rows which have `'C2017Value'` in range `261, 4760`

Comment: this can be your solution: [Python pandas slice dataframe by multiple index ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393856/python-pandas-slice-dataframe-by-multiple-index-ranges)

Comment: yes, this is a great solution for a single range...I would like to get all ['C2017Value'] column values which are within any of the ranges in the ranges list.

Comment: you can run `between(a, b)` in `for a,b in ranges` but it will check all rows in DF many times so it makes problem for big DF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply()` with function which checks value in ranges I can create new DF with results

```
def check_ranges(value):
    for a, b in ranges:
        if a <= value <= b:
            return True
    return False

results = df[ df['C2017Value'].apply(check_ranges) ]
```

---

Working code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['c1', 137674167],
        ['c2', 2166178],
        ['c3', 268],
     ], columns=['c', 'C2017Value'])

ranges = [
    (261, 4760),
    (12273391, 11104571063),
    (45695385, 4134339925),
    (15266178, 1376748162),
    (10106104, 97810284),
    (6492248, 588025190)
]

def check_ranges(value):
    for a, b in ranges:
        if a <= value <= b:
            return True
    return False

results = df[ df['C2017Value'].apply(check_ranges) ]

print(results)
```

Result:

```
   c   C2017Value
0  c1   137674167
2  c3         268
```

---

It can also get ranges as argument and then it needs `lambda`

```
def check_ranges(value, ranges):
    for a, b in ranges:
        if a <= value <= b:
            return True
    return False

results = df[ df['C2017Value'].apply(lambda x, r=ranges:check_ranges(x,r)) ]
```

---

**EDIT:** similar code can gives

```
    c  C2017Value                    range
0  c1   137674167  (12273391, 11104571063)
1  c2     2166178                     None
2  c3         268              (261, 4760)
```

It returns `(a, b)` instead of `True` and `None` instead of `False` (but it can return `False` or `NaN`)

```
def get_range(value, ranges):
    for a, b in ranges:
        if a <= value <= b:
            return (a, b)
    return None

df['range'] = df['C2017Value'].apply(lambda x, r=ranges:get_range(x,r))

print(df)
```

---

Working code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['c1', 137674167],
        ['c2', 2166178],
        ['c3', 268],
     ], columns=['c', 'C2017Value'])

ranges = [
    (261, 4760),
    (12273391, 11104571063),
    (45695385, 4134339925),
    (15266178, 1376748162),
    (10106104, 97810284),
    (6492248, 588025190)
]

def get_range(value, ranges):
    for a, b in ranges:
        if a <= value <= b:
            return (a, b)
    return None

df['range'] = df['C2017Value'].apply(lambda x, r=ranges:get_range(x,r))

print(df)

results = df[ df['range'].notnull() ]

print(results)
```

Result:

```
    c  C2017Value                    range
0  c1   137674167  (12273391, 11104571063)
1  c2     2166178                     None
2  c3         268              (261, 4760)

    c  C2017Value                    range
0  c1   137674167  (12273391, 11104571063)
2  c3         268              (261, 4760)
```

Comment: This solution looks great. I've tried the working code and am getting your results. Unfortunately, I'm trying the functions on my df and am getting a result that is an empty dataframe. I'm reviewing again now to see if I can locate the issue.

Comment: maybe add `print()` in `check_ranges` to see values in variables and test it with small part of your data.

Comment: it works! The ranges were inverted so I updated the ranges function and now check_ranges is working.

Comment: you could add in `check_ranges` - `if a>b: a,b = b,a`