# Creating a new row in pandas dataframe when there are more than four 'Code' columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame, each row with a unique pairing of 'group' and 'member', along with all 'codes' associated with that pairing in the subsequent rows. Below is a code I wrote to create a small sample of how it's structured:

```
import pandas as pd
member = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
group = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
dx1 = [11, 1232, 23, 346, 63, 346, 634]
dx2 = ["", 24, "", 2436, 346, 24, 97]
dx3 = ["", 2313, "", "", 987, 28, ""]
dx4 = ["", 234, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx5 = ["", 85, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx6 = ["", 4, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx7 = ["", 3, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx8 = ["", 9384, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx9 = ["", 38, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx0= ["", 3833, "", "", "", "", ""]

testdf = pd.DataFrame(data=[member, group, dx1, dx2, dx3, dx4, dx5, dx6, dx7, dx8, dx9, dx0])


cols=['group', 'member', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4','code5','code6','code7','code8','code9','code0']

dft = testdf.T
dft.columns = cols
dft
```

That code will produce this dataframe:

[Initial DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHxrD.png)

The actual data frame has thousands of rows. When there are more than four 'codes' listed on one row / group-member pairing, I wanted to create a new rows for every additional four codes past the first four. The resulting dataframe from transforming just the first two rows should look like this:

[Final Df (only the first two rows of Initial DF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2P9O.png)

I'm thinking some kind of conditional loop could be used to create a new df and append new rows accordingly, but for some reason my brain is stuck on how to do that. I apologize for not pasting the dataframes as text in this post, I am relatively new to posting on Stack (so if anyone has advice on pasting Pandas DF as text in Stack markdown that, too, would be amazing!) Any help is greatly appreciated.

** Note: In this example, row two is the only row that would be altered by the correct transformation because it's the only one with > 4 codes

Comment: Here is info on showing data frames on Stack Overflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks a lot @jsmart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[slicing multiple ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393856/python-pandas-slice-dataframe-by-multiple-index-ranges)
Using trick in link

1. replace empty strings in numeric columns with `np.nap`
2. slice out columns and required rows using `iloc`
3. left with effectively three things to `pd.concat()` after renaming columns appropriately
4. cleanup sort order and index

```py
import pandas as pd
member = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
group = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
dx1 = [11, 1232, 23, 346, 63, 346, 634]
dx2 = ["", 24, "", 2436, 346, 24, 97]
dx3 = ["", 2313, "", "", 987, 28, ""]
dx4 = ["", 234, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx5 = ["", 85, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx6 = ["", 4, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx7 = ["", 3, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx8 = ["", 9384, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx9 = ["", 38, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx0= ["", 3833, "", "", "", "", ""]

testdf = pd.DataFrame(data=[member, group, dx1, dx2, dx3, dx4, dx5, dx6, dx7, dx8, dx9, dx0])
cols=['group', 'member', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4','code5','code6','code7','code8','code9','code0']
dft = testdf.T
dft.columns = cols

dft = dft.replace({"":np.nan}) # just better for masks
mask5 = dft[~dft["code5"].isna()].index  # rows with a value in code 5
mask9 = dft[~dft["code9"].isna()].index  # rows with a value in code 9
# just concat them all together
dft = pd.concat([
    dft.iloc[:,0:6],
    # rename columns so they concat correctly
    dft.iloc[mask5,np.r_[0:2, 6:10]].rename({f"code{i+5}":f"code{i+1}" for i in range(4)}, axis=1),
    dft.iloc[mask9,np.r_[0:2, 10:12]].rename({"code9":"code1","code0":"code2"}, axis=1),
]).sort_values(["group","member"]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(dft.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
group member   code1   code2   code3   code4
     1      A    11.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
     1      B  1232.0    24.0  2313.0   234.0
     1      B    85.0     4.0     3.0  9384.0
     1      B    38.0  3833.0     NaN     NaN
     2      A    23.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
     2      B   346.0  2436.0     NaN     NaN
     2      C    63.0   346.0   987.0     NaN
     3      A   346.0    24.0    28.0     NaN
     3      B   634.0    97.0     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: This was great and super robust for my real dataset, which had 44000 rows and I had to partition into groups of 9 instead of 4. Thanks for this!

Comment: @EddieMcGolrick happy to hear it worked well.  For performance and code stability always work in paradigm of sets of data,  not looping

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

member = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
group = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
dx1 = [11, 1232, 23, 346, 63, 346, 634]
dx2 = ["", 24, "", 2436, 346, 24, 97]
dx3 = ["", 2313, "", "", 987, 28, ""]
dx4 = ["", 234, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx5 = ["", 85, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx6 = ["", 4, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx7 = ["", 3, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx8 = ["", 9384, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx9 = ["", 38, "", "", "", "", ""]
dx0= ["", 3833, "", "", "", "", ""]

testdf = pd.DataFrame(data=[member, group, dx1, dx2, dx3, dx4, dx5, dx6, dx7, dx8, dx9, dx0])

cols=['group', 'member', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4','code5','code6','code7','code8','code9','code0']

dft = testdf.T
dft.columns = cols

dfnewrows = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols[:6]) # for added rows

for idx,row in dft.iterrows():
   if (row['code5']): # wrap 2nd four codes if needed
        dfnewrows.loc[len(dfnewrows)+1] = [row['group'],row['member'],row['code5'],row['code6'],row['code7'],row['code8']]
   if (row['code9']): # wrap last codes if needed
        dfnewrows.loc[len(dfnewrows)+1] = [row['group'],row['member'],row['code9'],row['code0'],"", ""]

dfnew = dft[['group', 'member', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4']] # remove code5, code6,.....

dfnew = dfnew.append(dfnewrows) # add wrapped rows

dfnew = dfnew.sort_values(by=['group', 'member'])  # sort table

print(dfnew.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
group member code1 code2 code3 code4
    1      A    11
    1      B  1232    24  2313   234
    1      B    85     4     3  9384
    1      B    38  3833
    2      A    23
    2      B   346  2436
    2      C    63   346   987
    3      A   346    24    28
    3      B   634    97
```