# Multiple time range selection in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have time-series data in CSV format. I want to calculate the mean for a different selected time period on a single run of the script, e.g. `01-05-2017: 30-04-2018, 01-05-2018: 30-04-2019` so on. Below is sample data

[image]

I have a script but it's taking only one given time period. but I want to give the multiple time period as I mentioned above.

```
from datetime import datetime  
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Data\RT_2015_2020.csv', index_col=[0],parse_dates=[0])

z = df['2016-05-01' : '2017-04-30']
# Want to make like this way 
#z = df[['2016-05-01' : '2017-04-30'], ['2017-05-01' : '2018-04-30']] 
# It will calculate the mean for the selected time period
z.mean()
```

Comment: possible duplicate/related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393856/python-pandas-slice-dataframe-by-multiple-index-ranges

Comment: I tried it but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use dates as an index, you can extract the data with the conditions included in the desired range.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Date Mean
18-05-2016 0.31
07-06-2016 0.32
17-07-2016 0.50
15-09-2016 0.62
25-10-2016 0.63
04-11-2016 0.56
24-11-2016 0.56
14-12-2016 0.22
13-01-2017 0.22
23-01-2017 0.23
12-02-2017 0.21
22-02-2017 0.21 
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df['2016'].head()
    Mean
Date    
2016-05-18  0.31
2016-07-06  0.32
2016-07-17  0.50
2016-09-15  0.62
2016-10-25  0.63

df.loc['2016-05-01':'2017-01-30']
    Mean
Date    
2016-05-18  0.31
2016-07-06  0.32
2016-07-17  0.50
2016-09-15  0.62
2016-10-25  0.63
2016-11-24  0.56
2016-12-14  0.22
2017-01-13  0.22
2017-01-23  0.23

df.loc['2016-05-01':'2017-01-30'].mean()
Mean    0.401111
dtype: float64
```