# How could I save specific row ranges from csv-s?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So what my code does is merging same size (same numbers of columns and rows) csv-s horizontally.
The csv-s are quite big (1M rows each) so I want to save a file only from row 0-20 and 70-80 with an empty row between them. Is it possible?

Ideally the code wouldn't even merge the csv-s completely only the needed range from all of them

```
import pandas as pd
import os


def get_df():
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    os.chdir("C:/Users/DD/Desktop/TM/Simulations/1-2")
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            aux=pd.read_csv(file, error_bad_lines=False)
            df = pd.concat([df, aux], axis=1, join='outer')


    return df

df=get_df()

df.to_csv(f"file_name.csv")
```

Comment: Good suggestions here, like using `.iloc[np._r[]]` to slice [Python pandas slice dataframe by multiple index ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393856/python-pandas-slice-dataframe-by-multiple-index-ranges). I think his would look like `df = pd.concat([df.iloc[np._r[0:20,70:80]], axis=1, join='outer')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
I think that for np.r_ is only working for rows, but changing it to np.c_ is also not solving my problem for some reason, it keep saying that "positional indexers are out-of-bounds"

Comment: You say you want only **rows** 0-20, so `r_` would be appropriate, no?

Comment: oh yes you are right!
Same error message tho :/

Comment: Curious. It's suggesting that those index ranges don't exist. There is more than 79 rows of data in `aux` when this error is thrown, right?

Comment: oh yes, much more, like 1million rows

Comment: I've added an answer illustrating this technique. It's working fine for some randomly generated dataframes.

Comment: I just dont get it, all the csv-s has 2 columns and countless rows with numbers, but for size it says 0... probably thats why its out of bounds.

Comment: it must be because of the df=pd.DataFrame() line in the original code i think

Answer (score 1):

Bringing this down from the comments. Using `iloc[np.r_[]]` as suggested in the first comment works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.iloc[np.r_[0:20,70:80]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('EFGH'))
display(pd.concat([df, df2.iloc[np.r_[0:20,70:80]]], axis=1, join='outer'))


+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| idx | A  | B  | C  | D  | E  | F  | G  | H  |
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   0 | 47 | 31 | 52 | 91 | 65 |  3 | 77 | 58 |
|   1 | 10 | 32 | 21 | 36 | 28 | 72 | 31 | 93 |
|   2 | 29 | 96 |  2 | 69 | 72 | 47 | 59 | 78 |
|   3 | 69 | 31 | 76 | 42 | 96 | 26 | 59 | 36 |
|   4 | 50 | 49 | 66 |  2 |  4 | 38 | 97 | 11 |
|   5 | 72 | 29 | 74 | 90 | 79 | 84 | 39 | 10 |
|   6 |  6 |  5 | 43 | 31 | 64 | 37 | 68 |  4 |
|   7 | 93 |  8 | 52 | 19 | 15 | 68 | 58 | 20 |
|   8 | 91 | 23 | 99 | 31 | 95 | 36 | 51 | 65 |
|   9 | 68 | 68 | 65 | 21 | 23 | 22 |  6 | 30 |
|  10 | 29 | 35 |  3 | 62 | 44 | 33 | 28 | 17 |
|  11 | 44 | 89 | 13 | 83 | 35 | 28 | 93 | 95 |
|  12 | 48 | 25 |  7 | 67 | 33 | 21 | 33 | 30 |
|  13 | 28 | 93 | 92 | 82 | 83 | 48 |  4 | 51 |
|  14 | 50 | 50 | 15 | 25 |  2 | 57 | 15 | 73 |
|  15 |  4 | 77 | 78 | 68 | 35 |  0 | 49 | 16 |
|  16 | 57 | 53 | 87 |  5 | 50 | 31 | 55 | 79 |
|  17 | 46 | 21 | 36 | 15 | 85 | 43 | 64 | 20 |
|  18 | 43 | 62 | 23 | 35 | 85 | 71 | 37 | 52 |
|  19 | 27 | 36 | 73 | 60 | 16 | 22 | 37 | 42 |
|  70 | 46 | 86 | 93 | 66 | 13 | 57 |  4 | 68 |
|  71 | 68 | 30 | 42 | 60 | 99 | 31 | 50 | 42 |
|  72 | 31 | 91 | 41 | 18 | 75 | 88 | 83 | 15 |
|  73 | 25 |  5 | 53 | 31 | 16 | 33 | 64 | 74 |
|  74 | 35 | 56 | 58 | 91 | 34 | 75 | 29 | 38 |
|  75 | 66 | 10 | 36 | 37 | 33 | 36 | 10 |  2 |
|  76 | 99 | 43 | 22 | 38 | 52 | 54 |  0 | 77 |
|  77 | 76 | 58 | 89 | 25 | 79 | 16 | 50 | 23 |
|  78 | 15 | 59 | 20 |  4 | 83 | 69 | 60 | 36 |
|  79 | 81 | 12 |  0 | 92 | 43 | 22 | 16 |  4 |
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```