# Python - How to replace values in a Pandas row based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, drop

Following up on a previous question of mine from the same project, I have a Pandas dataframe `sheet` that looks something like this:

| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NaN | 2022 | 2022 | 2022 | NaN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 | text2 | text3 | NaN | text4 | text5 | text6 | NaN |
| 2 | value1 | value2 | value3 | NaN | value4 | value5 | value6 | NaN |

Following the second `NaN` column, the pattern repeats with subsequent years until 2030.

First, I would like to delete the **first** `NaN` column while keeping the rest.

Secondly, I would like to then replace all the `NaN` at index `1` with `text7`.

Regarding the first problem, I tried the following:

`sheet.drop(columns = sheet.columns[3], axis = 1, inplace=True`

However, that just dropped EVERY column identical to the one I wanted to drop instead of just the one. I couldn't figure that out, so I just moved onto my second goal with the following:

```
values_to_replace = {'NaN':'Next Deadline'}
sheet.iloc[1].replace(values_to_replace,inplace=True)
```

However, that just spits out:

```
#SettingWithCopyWarning: 
#A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

And nothing in my dataframe changes. I even tried turning that warning off, to no avail.

Help on either of these would be much appreciated as I've spent far too long on them and would like to move on, thank you!

Comment: The warning is telling you why your dataframe doesn't change: you are setting a value on a copy of a slice from a dataframe (`sheet.iloc[1]`). You need to assign the result of the operation back to the location (and remove the `inplace=True` from the `replace`)

Comment: Thanks! This helped me with my `replace` issue, but my `.drop()` is still dropping more than just the targeted column - any ideas on that front?

Comment: I've posted an answer which should solve both problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is caused by `drop` dropping *all* columns called `NaN`. To work around this, take slices from the dataframe (using the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39393929/9473764)):

```py
import numpy as np

sheet = sheet.iloc[:, np.r_[:3, 4:len(sheet.columns)]]
```

For your second issue, the warning is telling you why your dataframe doesn't change: you are setting a value on a *copy* of a slice from a dataframe (`sheet.iloc[1]`). You need to assign the result of the operation back to the location (and remove the `inplace=True` from the `replace`) i.e.

```
sheet.iloc[1] = sheet.iloc[1].replace(values_to_replace)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer re: `drop`. I realized after posting that it was, as you said, dropping all columns named `NaN`.  I've employed the line you suggested, but if I read it correctly, this just selects the column I want to operate on. So, I tried this:

```sheet = sheet.drop(sheet.iloc[:, np.r_[:3, 4:len(sheet.columns)]], axis=1)```

Which didn't do anything either. What am I missing here?

Comment: @NickSeymour no, this will select all the columns *other* than the one you want to remove. So basically it says give me every column *except* column 3.

Comment: If you try just typing `sheet.iloc[:, np.r_[:3, 4:len(sheet.columns)]]` you should see `sheet` with every column but the first `NaN` column.