# Pandas - Times series multiple slices of a dataframe groupby Id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, slice

What I have:

A dataframe, `df` consists of 3 columns (`Id, Item and Timestamp`). Each subject has unique `Id` with recorded `Item` on a particular date and time (`Timestamp`). The second dataframe, `df_ref` consists of date time range reference for slicing the `df`, the `Start` and the `End` for each subject, `Id`.

`df`:

```
         Id      Item      Timestamp
   0     1       aaa       2011-03-15 14:21:00
   1     1       raa       2012-05-03 04:34:01
   2     1       baa       2013-05-08 22:21:29
   3     1       boo       2015-12-24 21:53:41
   4     1       afr       2016-04-14 12:28:26
   5     1       aud       2017-05-10 11:58:02
   6     2       boo       2004-06-22 22:20:58
   7     2       aaa       2005-11-16 07:00:00
   8     2       ige       2006-06-28 17:09:18
   9     2       baa       2008-05-22 21:28:00
   10    2       boo       2017-06-08 23:31:06
   11    3       ige       2011-06-30 13:14:21
   12    3       afr       2013-06-11 01:38:48
   13    3       gui       2013-06-21 23:14:26
   14    3       loo       2014-06-10 15:15:42
   15    3       boo       2015-01-23 02:08:35
   16    3       afr       2015-04-15 00:15:23
   17    3       aaa       2016-02-16 10:26:03
   18    3       aaa       2016-06-10 01:11:15
   19    3       ige       2016-07-18 11:41:18
   20    3       boo       2016-12-06 19:14:00
   21    4       gui       2016-01-05 09:19:50
   22    4       aaa       2016-12-09 14:49:50  
   23    4       ige       2016-11-01 08:23:18
```

`df_ref`:

```
         Id     Start                   End
    0    1      2013-03-12 00:00:00     2016-05-30 15:20:36
    1    2      2005-06-05 08:51:22     2007-02-24 00:00:00
    2    3      2011-05-14 10:11:28     2013-12-31 17:04:55
    3    3      2015-03-29 12:18:31     2016-07-26 00:00:00
```

What I want:

Slice the `df` dataframe based on the data time range given for each `Id` (groupby Id) in `df_ref` and concatenate the sliced data into new dataframe. However, a subject could have more than one date time range (in this example `Id`=3 has 2 date time range).

`df_expected`:

```
         Id      Item      Timestamp
     0   1       baa       2013-05-08 22:21:29
     1   1       boo       2015-12-24 21:53:41
     2   1       afr       2016-04-14 12:28:26
     3   2       aaa       2005-11-16 07:00:00
     4   2       ige       2006-06-28 17:09:18
     5   3       ige       2011-06-30 13:14:21
     6   3       afr       2013-06-11 01:38:48
     7   3       gui       2013-06-21 23:14:26
     8   3       afr       2015-04-15 00:15:23
     9   3       aaa       2016-02-16 10:26:03
     10  3       aaa       2016-06-10 01:11:15
     11  3       ige       2016-07-18 11:41:18
```

What I have done so far:

I referred to this post ([Time series multiple slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441243/pandas-time-series-multiple-slice)) while doing my code. I modify the code since it does not have the groupby element which I need.

My code:

```
from datetime import datetime

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

x = pd.DataFrame()
for pid in def_ref.Id.unique():
    selection = df[(df['Id']== pid) & (df['Timestamp']>= def_ref['Start']) & (df['Timestamp']<= def_ref['End'])]
    x = x.append(selection)
```

Above code give error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join, also it create all combinations for duplicated `Id`. Then filter by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filtering by conditions and by `df1.columns` in one step:

```
df1 = df.merge(df_ref, on='Id')
df2 = df1.loc[df1['Timestamp'].between(df1['Start'], df1['End']), df.columns]
print (df2)
    Id Item           Timestamp
2    1  baa 2013-05-08 22:21:29
3    1  boo 2015-12-24 21:53:41
4    1  afr 2016-04-14 12:28:26
7    2  aaa 2005-11-16 07:00:00
8    2  ige 2006-06-28 17:09:18
11   3  ige 2011-06-30 13:14:21
13   3  afr 2013-06-11 01:38:48
15   3  gui 2013-06-21 23:14:26
22   3  afr 2015-04-15 00:15:23
24   3  aaa 2016-02-16 10:26:03
26   3  aaa 2016-06-10 01:11:15
28   3  ige 2016-07-18 11:41:18
```