# Select multiple columns by labels in pandas not all in order

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select a set of columns from a pandas dataframe, but only some of these columns are in sequential order. 
E.g., I would like to write something like:

```
df.loc[:,['a','2001':'2040']]
```

A similar question has been asked here, but the answers are not helpful: [Select multiple columns by labels (pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241836/select-multiple-columns-by-labels-pandas)

In my case, doing this manually is too cumbersome. Regular expressions are possible but complicated because the slice is number-oriented not text-oriented. So what is the most simple approach?

Comment: Maybe use a range to create your list of columns? `col_list=[str(i) for i in range(2001,2040)]` and then append additional elements as needed? Then df.loc[:,col_list]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
In [11]: df.columns
Out[11]: Index(['a', '2001', '2002', '2040', '2041'], dtype='object')

In [12]: [c for c in df.columns if c == "a" or c.isdigit() and 2001 <= int(c) <= 2040 ]
Out[12]: ['a', '2001', '2002', '2040']

In [13]: df[[c for c in df.columns if c == "a" or c.isdigit() and 2001 <= int(c) <= 2040 ]]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect and instructive.