# Simultaneous multiple subsetting columns of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given a dataframe say `df1` with say 100 columns and 100 rows, I want a subset of the columns. I want to index two(or multiple) chunks of the columns simultaneously.

For instance, I want something like:

`df1[:, [1:20, 55:57]]`  (obviously, this doesn't work)

But I want columns 1 through 20 as well as columns 55 through 57. I could do this with the two separate operations and join them but I was wondering if there's a functionality that allows this on a single take (I know **R** has that functionality, hence the curiosity).

EDIT: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241836/select-multiple-columns-by-labels-pandas) but the answer is for strings. A solution where multiple subsetting could be done would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy.r_:

```
import numpy as np
df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:20, 55:57]]
```

Comment: This makes things so much easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of column numbers:

```
df.iloc[:, list(range(1,21)) + (list(range(55,58)))]
```